# How can I expand a TextCtrl in wxypython ONLY horizontally?

Tags: python, wxpython

I've tried:

```
# Inside a GridBagSizer
self.sizer.Add(self.mytextctrl, (0, 0), (1, 15), wx.GROW)
```

I've also tried:

```
self.sizer.Add(self.mytextctrl, (0, 0), (1, 15), wx.EXPAND)
```

In both these cases, the widget is expanded in height and length. I only wanted to increase the length (horizontally). Is there a style flag for this?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use the sizer's `AddGrowableCol()` method to accomplish this. Here's an example:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        bag = wx.GridBagSizer(3, 3)

        txt = wx.TextCtrl(self)
        bag.Add(txt, pos=(0,0), flag=wx.EXPAND, border=5)
        bag.AddGrowableCol(0)

        self.SetSizer(bag)


########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Bag sizer')
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

You could also experiment with setting the span for the widget and see if that works for you too. However I didn't have much luck with that method.

Normally what I like to do is nest BoxSizers. I feel that this gives me much more control over my layout, although it does take a bit more time upfront in planning.

Comment: This didn't work either. The reason is if we put something like `bag.Add(btn, pos=(0,1), border=5)` after the textctrl, the button being bigger in height than the textctrl will stretch the entire row's height. Since flag `wx.EXPAND` is set for the textctrl it will now fill this elevated height. You could compare it by adding one more row with just the textctrl - it will look smaller in height than the one above it (with a button to its right). Also, you could see from my code above that I've already tried span method.